# Extracting time-tagged pulses from Geiger audio recording

Tags: peak-detection, sensor, pulse

I am doing some tests with SmartGeiger detector designed for smartphones. The sensor unit sends pulses via phone microphone jack input and the app does the counting and calculates the values.

However, I need to record and process a lot of data and the app is not comfortable for this task (you have to save every value manually). I recorded the data with Audacity - looks this way:

[image: Audacity screenshot]

but I need to somehow convert it to the pulses - e.g. pick up the pulse data using some simple threshold filter and count the number of pulses for particular time interval.

One pulse looks this way in the audio data:

[image: Audacity screenshot - one pulse]

Unfortunately the Audacity "Sample Data Export" feature:
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/sample_data_export.html

seems to only work for short parts of the data. Is there any way to do the conversion? 
I only need the temporal location of the pulses.

thanks

Comment: What have you considered doing and what software would you be able to use to process this?  You have such a relatively low noise level, what is the significance of positive versus negative going pulses? Would you have situations where there is only what you would consider as one pulse but you actually measure two pulses very close together? If that isn't a concern they threshold with hysteresis would be a straightforward solution for you.

Comment: Hi, I added second screenshot and more details. One particle does one pulse consisting both the positive and negative peak. So, in principle it is not important whether to only use the positive or the negative peaks and drop the rest - the time difference is not so important there.

Comment: So why not just do an absolute value and detect on threshold crossing; hold off for your assumed minimum pulse width to reset for the next count? I don’t quite see the question or challenge here so I am likely missing something that is making this more complicated than that for you. What software will you use?

Comment: I was rather asking for suggestion of particular software / script solution :-) I know roughly what to do but no idea how to do it...

Comment: Nearly any software would do this- Matlab, Python, Octave—- what do you have experience with? If none download Octave and learn it- it is free

Comment: None yet. Currently experimenting with ffmpeg (found meanwhile): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056970/ffmpeg-txt-from-audio-levels and simple sorting in spreadsheet... will see.

Comment: @Juhele then, really, Octave, or Python (I personally lean towards Python, because it has a wider applicability, but Octave might be slightly easier. Then again, python can be run on a phone, don't know if someone ported the octave runtime to android...). I think if you can already deal with the things in your head algorithmically in spreadsheets, then this will be pretty easy for you, once you're familiar with any language.